# Similar Haskell list comprehensions with different results

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I don't understand why these two similar list comprehensions give different results:

```
Prelude> let t2s n= [ 1/(2*i) | i <- [1,3..n]]
Prelude> t2s 0
[0.5]
Prelude> let t2s n= [   (2*i) | i <- [1,3..n]]
Prelude> t2s 0
[]
```

I expected both to return `[]` on argument `0`. I must be missing something silly?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that

```
enumFromThenTo 1.0 3.0 0.0
```

evaluates to `[1.0]`. The specification of `enumFromThenTo` for Floats can be found in section 6.3.4 of http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html .

Comment: For increasing floats, [a,b..c] keeps going until the numbers exceed c + (b-a)/2.0. For example [1.0, 2.0 .. 4.0] is [1.0, 3.0, 5.0].

Comment: What happened to 2.0 and 4.0 in your example?

Comment: @Code-Guru. Mea culpa. I meant [1.0, 3.0 .. 4.0].  Thanks.

Comment: Here's an example that better shows why the specification kind of makes sense. Consider `[0.1, 0.4 .. 0.9]`. The answer is `[0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1.0]`, which is 'better' than the alternative of `[0.1, 0.4, 0.7]` in the sense that |1.0 - 0.9| < |0.7 - 0.9|. In your example `[1.0, 3.0 .. 0.0]` the choice of the "last" number in the list is between 1.0 and -1.0 (-1.0 being 2 less than 1.0, see?). Both are equally close to 0.0; when there is a tie, the standard chooses the one that makes the list longer. Whether this choice is arbitrary or intended to make empty list errors less likely, I don't know.

Comment: In my answer I implied that the type of 1.0, 3.0, and 0.0 is Float.  WinHugs 98 tells me that the their type is `Fractional a => a` and the standards (98 & 2010) seem to agree. What I don't get is this: `Fractional a` doesn't inherit from `Enum a` (or am I wrong?), so how does the expression `enumFromThenTo 1.0 3.0 0.0` pass the type checker? If it is because `a` defaults to `Double`, then why is the type of `enumFromThenTo 1.0 3.0 0.0` `Fractional a => [a]` rather than `[Double]`?

Comment: `:t enumFromThenTo 1.0` says `enumFromThenTo 1.0 :: (Fractional t, Enum t) => t -> t -> [t]` so the concrete type will have to define instances for both type classes. Both `Float` and `Double` have instances for `Enum` and `Fractional`. (say `> :i Enum` and `> :i Fractional` to see it).

Comment: @Will Ness. Ok. That makes sense. I see how it type checks. Then it seems defaulting kicks in after type inference, as the type reported by :t does not have defaults applied.

Comment: @Norvell - yes, 1.0 is closer to 0.9 than 0.7, but I don't see the relevance of that, since the spec is to enumerate all values "up to" (but not exceeding) 0.9. I certainly get the idea that floats are not exact because of finite precision, but it does surprise me that in a sequence asking for values up to 0.0 1.0 is included; this is not a precision issue(!). But (of course) the spec does state this behavior... Thanks for the reference and pointer.

Comment: I wonder why the enumFromThenTo rule for Floats is so "liberal" about overrunning the end point. Why doesn't use some smaller increment, like increment/100 instead of i/2? Surely i/2 is not generally even close to actual Float precision error limits.

Comment: The reason for the 1/2 is so that the "last" value is as close as possible to the "sentinel" value (third arg) In isolation, that might be a good design decision. But it violates the "principle of least surprise" because it is significantly different from the rule for integers. We expect that two instances of the same type class should have behaviour that is somehow "maximally analogous".  I think the answer is "round off error". If they'd gone with the analogous "up to but not exceeding" rule, `[0.1, 0.2 .. 1.0]` might only have 9 members in some implementations and that is surely surprising.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I changed the name of your first `t2s` to `t1s`, so that I can have them both loaded into ghci at the same time. Look at the inferred types for each of them:

```
[ts.hs:2:1-33] *Main> :t t1s
t1s :: (Enum t, Fractional t) => t -> [t]
[ts.hs:2:1-33] *Main> :t t2s
t2s :: (Enum t, Num t) => t -> [t]
[ts.hs:2:1-33] *Main>
```

Note that `t1s` takes a `Fractional` argument whereas `t2s` takes a `Num`. This means that in `t1s 0`, the `0` is inferred to be a `Double`. On the other hand, the interpreter infers `0` to be a `Integer` in `t2s 0`. Since the type used for the argument differs, the behavior can differ in very surprising ways. In particular, you should be sure to use only `Integral` types when enumerating a list as in `[1,3..n]`.

To fix this, you simply need to provide explicit type signatures for both functions.

Comment: Defaulting strikes again! Basically, the type inference finds the most general type. The problem is that numeric literals are overloaded, so an expression like `t2s 0` is ambiguous--it can be valid for *any* numeric type! Since ambiguities like this are common and we want to be able to use Haskell like a calculator, we have a hacky way to deal with it: [defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4). Essentially, we just first try `Integer` and then try `Double` for expressions like this. You might want to edit something about this into your answer.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis I'm a Haskell newb and didn't know about defaulting until you posted this comment. My answer posted here simply came from hacking at the OP's code because I was curious about the differences, too. I found the type differences when I `:step`ed through the evaluation.

Comment: It's as good a time to learn about it as any :). I actually first read about it when answering an SO question too. In fact, that's how I picked up a whole bunch of tidbits like that.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis I've learned quite a bit, as well, while reading or attempting to answer SO questions. Of course, most of these I have forgotten. Thankfully I can outsource my memory to Google when a need arises.

Comment: Thanks; actually my code was: sum [ ...], so I would have to break things out (unnecessarily?) to be able to specify the type of this expression in the sum term, so I'm not sure how I might do that nicely.

Comment: You should be able to specify the type of a subexpression without "breaking things out", as you say. Of course, breaking large expressions into smaller expressions is a very common Haskell-ism. For further help, please edit your question with the full expression you want to evaluate.